# Calculate counter for multiprocessing map function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

Using multiprocessing map function to speed up my geocoding script. It is working nicely but I need to add a counter to each record

```
ids=[24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760]

def linestring(d):
    args={'segmentID': d}
    resp=requests.get('http://geocoder?',params=args)
    data= resp.json()[0]['GeomWebMercator']
    feature = {'type':'Feature',
                'properties':{},
                'geometry':{'type':'LineString','coordinates': None}}
    feature['geometry']['coordinates']=data['coordinates'][0]
    feature['properties']['id']=d
    return feature

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
    result = pool.map(linestring, ids)
```

for each record the counter will get a plus one. Is there a way to do this with the map function?

something like this

```
c=0
for x in li:
    c+=1
    print c
```

I am aware I can iterate over this list after the map function and add a plus one but I am not looking to do this

Comment: what is the actual URL (to test)?

Comment: its an internal url...

Comment: What do you mean by "return a counter to each feature"?

Comment: just a simple +=1, sorry I just cannot word it. I will post a simple example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out what I wanted to do. I needed to add another parameter in the function and pass an iterable item through that as the second argument

```
ids=[24381, 31883,  21145, 21143, 23010, 23016, 28066, 28163, 28673, 68665, 50750, 35268, 34943, 76377, 29760]

def linestring(d,c):
    args={'segmentID': d}
    resp=requests.get('http://geocoder?',params=args)
    data= resp.json()[0]['GeomWebMercator']
    feature = {'type':'Feature',
                'properties':{},
                'geometry':{'type':'LineString','coordinates': None}}
    feature['geometry']['coordinates']=data['coordinates'][0]
    feature['properties']['id']=d
    feature['properties']['counter']=c
    return feature

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = mp.Pool(processes = 8)
    result = pool.map(linestring, ids,xrange(len(ids)))
```

I was not aware you can pass multiple arguments through the map function

Comment: So you were looking for something like `enumerate(ids)` and `index,d = arg`.